# Insert datetime to database

Tags: java, sql, datetime, sqldatetime

```
Date currentDateTime;
java.sql.Date sql_currentDateTime;
currentDateTime = getCurrentDateTime(); //Fri Jun 21 15:53:59 AZST 2013
sql_currentDateTime = new java.sql.Date(currentDateTime.getTime()); //2013-06-21

PreparedStatement insertStmt = null;
sqlToMessage = "insert into message values (?)";
insertStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlToMessage);
insertStmt.setDate(1, sql_currentDateTime);
insertStmt.executeUpdate();
```

I want to insert current date time (20-Jun-13 16:04:32) into database. But data inserted to database like that `20-Jun-13`, not like `20-Jun-13 16:04:32`. How to solve it ? thank u

Comment: what is the date column data type? Uset `Timestamp` instead of `Date`

Comment: The column type in the table is probably not of a timestamp type and only holds the date.

Comment: DATE and TIMESTAMP column data types store date and time information. 
**DATE stores a moment in time with precision including day, month, year, hours, 
minutes, and seconds.** TIMESTAMP(f) stores the same information as DATE but is 
also capable of storing fractional seconds (From McGraw.Hill.Osborne.Media.OCA.Oracle.Database.11g.SQL.Fundamentals.I.Exam.Guide.Exam.1Z0-051.May.2008). Any other solution without changing data type of record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of `java.sql.Date`.

The `java.sql.Timestamp` has the date and the time. Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

Also, it is **important** that the column of the table is of type `Timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

change the databse column from date to timestamp